# OpenLayers, Get clustered point's val

Tags: openlayers, gis

I'm working on a map with WMS overlays and a lot of markers, my problem is when I try to calculate the average of points clustered, I've found how to differentiate the behaviour and the label text depending on the number of clustered elements, but I don't know how to reach the "val" value of every clustered point to calculate their average and show in the clustered point.

I think values are into features.cluster array (if I look into it with .toString() I get different numbers of [object][object],[object][object] etc), but I can't understand how to reach those values.

This is the context code:

```
context: {
    val: function(feature) { 
       if(feature.attributes.count>1) {
           [here I should show the average]
       } else return feature.attributes.val; 
    },
[...]
```

And this is just some from the OpenLayers.Style code:

```
var pointStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    strokeWidth: "${strokeFunction}",
    fillColor: "${fillFunction}",
    label: "${val}",
    [...]
```

Don't think it's needed, but this is the point code where I set the val variable:

```
[...]
var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
     pointFeature.attributes = {
         val: mks[i].m,
         align: "cm"
     };
```

(mks[i].m is the value I get from a JSON array, it's a number with decimals)

I really appreciate any help you can provide,
Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been answered on gis.stackexchange,
this is the link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79788/openlayers-get-clustered-points-val

This is what I needed (treating feature.cluster[i].attributes as an array):

```
var sumValue = 0;
for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) {
    sumValue += feature.cluster[i].attributes['val'];
}
var averageValue = sumValue/feature.cluster.length;
return averageValue;
```

Thanks to Mingfeng